# How can I implement a generic function in scala that allows arguments that can be added and sums them?

Tags: scala, generics

How would I define a generic function if I wanted to ensure that its arguments were able to be added together?

```
def f[A <: (addition??)](first: A, second: A): Unit = println(first + second)
```

Comment: How are you deciding whether two values can be added together? It is not as simple as testing for a `+` operator, unfortunately.

Comment: just a generic solution that allows values that can be combined with the plus operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By providing [Semigroup](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/semigroup.html) typeclass instances and infix `+` operator via extension method, for example

```
trait Semigroup[A] {
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A
}

case class Foo(v: Int)
case class Bar(a: String, b: String)

implicit val fooSemigroup: Semigroup[Foo] = (x: Foo, y: Foo) => Foo(x.v + y.v)
implicit val barSemigroup: Semigroup[Bar] = (x: Bar, y: Bar) => Bar(x.a + y.a, x.b + y.b)

implicit class SemigroupOps[A](x: A) {
  def +(y: A)(implicit ev: Semigroup[A]): A = ev.combine(x, y)
}

Foo(41) + Foo(1)                     // res0: Foo = Foo(42)
Bar("He", "wo") + Bar("llo", "rld")  // res1: Bar = Bar(Hello,world)
```

Now your method can be constrained like so

```
def f[A](first: A, second: A)(implicit ev: Semigroup[A]): Unit = 
  println(first + second)
```

---

<sub>This answer attempts to just illustrate the concept, so in practice, heed Luis' comment and use out-of-the-box cats facilities.</sub>

Comment: Being honest, I would just use the `|+|` operator already provided by **Semigroup**. I would be really reluctant to overload `+` since it already works for any type by turning everything into string concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about adding numeric values, you can use the `Numeric` typeclass like this:

```
def f[A](first: A, second: A)(implicit n: Numeric[A]): Unit =
  println(n.plus(first, second))
```

For more general "addition" you will have to define your own typeclass that specifies how to "add" two values together.

There are plenty of articles out there about Scala typeclasses, so pick one that looks sensible to you, or check the many questions here about them!

[ Or see the answer by Mario Galic :) ]

Comment: @MarioGalic Thanks, that was my suspicion, and it is good to know that it gets detected.